# How to implement search like in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, string, search

This is the functionality I want to achieve: a search result has to contain the search key, even if there are some letters missing in between. So, for example, if a user wants to search for `noodles` and accidentally misspells it and types in `nooles`, the correct search result still pops up. Here are some other examples:

[image]

[image]

I think I need to break the search key down into combinations of two halves. Then show results that contain both halves of the key. Has someone done something like this? What if I break it into three or four parts? What if i break it into one-character strings and the only requirement is for the result to contain all the letters the search key contains?

Comment: I would suggest you look up the phrases "soundex" and "fuzzy matching" rather than try to guess what Android Studio does. e.g Fuzzy matching. FWIW, I use this feature in emacs to great benefits. http://www.georgestragand.com/dice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this enough but I just wrote this and it seems to work. Please provide other answers, that use another approach!

```
// returns true if a result string contains key 
// (or any combination of its letters in order)
private boolean contains(String result, String key) {
    // make both strings lowercase and remove spaces
    result = result.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");  
    key = key.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");

    // use a char array
    char[] letters = key.toCharArray();

    // loop through it
    for (char c : letters) {
        if (!result.contains(c + "")) {
            return false;   // stop searching if can't find at least one char
        }

        // remove the first part of the string, so that we're searching for 
        // letters that exist in a string in order they appear in the key.
        result = result.substring(result.indexOf(c));
    }

    return true;
}
```